# Chromium unpacked extensions syncing

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, sync, google-chrome-extensions

I am trying to sync extensions between Chromium browser and two Windows 7 PC's.

- Windows 7 PC's x2
- Chromium Version 50.0.2626.0

So far I have downloaded the Chromium Installer [from here](http://chromium.woolyss.com/). I have installed this on to both PC's, and signed in as the Google user. It's a fresh install so there are no bookmarks or favourites. As a test I created two bookmark folders on PC1 and these do sync between both PCs - I can see them appear on PC2 after a few seconds.

I then installed an **unpacked extension** extension on PC1, however this never appears on PC2. I have went to settings > extensions > checked 'Developer Mode' and clicked 'update extensions now' - nothing.

Things I have tried so far;

- logging out/in of the browser
- restart browser
- clear browser cache/history/settings
- disconnect/reconnect my Google account from both browsers
- restart both PC's
- uninstall/re-install CHromium on both PC's
- waited 15 minutes (thought there may have been a delay in sync)
- tried same process in Ubuntu 14.04

When I install a 'normal' extension from the Chrome Web Store they appear and sync just fine. So what's the issue with unpacked extensions? I am clicking 'Load unpacked extension', browsing to the (extracked) folder, and importing. The extension appears on PC1 but **never** on PC2.

I have a number of unpacked extensions extensions that I need synced.

I have included some images of my settings if this helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas as to what else I can do or check?

Comment: What does https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync show?

If you don't see the extensions showing there make sure it's enabled by going to Settings -> Advanced Sync Settings

Comment: it appears you've loaded this extension from your local drive which isn't tracked by google and thus not synced. Try installing from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-keyboard/pflmllfnnabikmfkkaddkoolinlfninn?hl=en instead.

Comment: Well that's the problem...google syncs only what it knows you've installed from their webstore not what you've installed locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I agree with JasonSec. Sync doesn't work for unpacked extensions because they are loaded locally.
And the reload option simply load the extension again from you hdd.

I don't know if it fits your needs, but you can always use a remote file instead of a local file (js html etc.).

E.g.:

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.site2rumyourextension.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "YourJS.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}],
```

YourJS.js:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'https://code.yourdomain.com/yourAllwaysUpdatedJS.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

This way you can update your extension code without reload or sync it in all the browsers!

Note: I'm not sure if you can put your online js url directly on the manifest, but this way works for sure.

Comment: More details added to the answer.

Comment: Hi johnny_s this workaround works for you?

Answer (score 0):

OP loaded unpacked extensions via local drive which isn't tracked by google and thus not synced., google only syncs web store extensions which is why the sync feature is not working.