# Install one Google Chrome extension on one device only, but keep syncing all others?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

I want to sync Chrome between my home laptop and my work PC **including extensions**. **Some** extensions however I need to have on only one device for various reasons.

Examples would be

- Having StayFocusd only on the work PC
- Circumventing PushBullet's limitation ("all chrome browsers count as one device") by using the extension at the Linux-based work PC, and the Windows program on the home laptop.

## Similar Questions, that are not duplicates

- [Disable Chrome extensions at one location only](https://superuser.com/questions/616075/disable-chrome-extensions-at-one-location-only) is about making *all* extensions specific to one device. Though it could be used as a workaround in my case, it would add extra inconvenience for extensions I *want* synchronized, which would defeat the purpose of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the extension to zip file with a chrome extension downloader and unzip the file, then go to extensions and turn on developer mode.
Click on load unpacked extension and select your unzipped folder.
(Chrome only syncs extensions downloaded from the store [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/1028932/chromium-unpacked-extensions-syncing))

Comment: To disable developer extension warning see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-in-chrome)